# Hiding items in android multichoice dialog

Tags: android, dialog

i am building a multichoice dialog :

```
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
  options[i] = ...;
  checked[i] = ...;
}

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Options");
builder.setMultiChoiceItems(options, checked, optionsDialogListener);

...

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

But now i need some of the items to be invisible/disabled, but i still need them in my options array.

Is there a way to achieve this? I know its not the right way, but I rather would not create a custom Adapter. I'm looking for something like "getChildAt"

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the the related `ListView` with ...

```
ListView listView = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
```

Having the list view you can attach your own adapter implementation (e.g. `MyAdapter` extended from `ArrayAdapter`) to the `ListView` ...

```
listView.setAdapter(
    new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, 
                        new String[] {"Option 1","Option 2","Option 3"}));

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int psn, long id) {
        // just as an example: disable all choices
        enabled = new boolean[] {false, false, false};
    }
});
```

... that overrides the `boolean isEnabled(int position)` method the way you need it:

```
// maintain your enabled and disabled status here
static boolean enabled[] = {true, true, true}; 

// own adapter relying overriding isEnabled
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int n) {
        return enabled[n]; 
    }
}
```

After changing conditions/flags for `isEnabled` you might have to call ...

```
listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

... in order to redraw the list view (though, it seemed not to be necessary in my test code). You can control the list view item style by changing `simple_list_item_single_choice` to  `simple_list_item_multiple_choice` or something else (check code completion or create an own layout optionally).

Hope this helps ... Cheers!

Comment: Hi, listView.setItemChecked(position, false); works, but listView.getChildAt(position).setEnabled(false);  doesnt. Im getting a 0 value for listView.getChildCount(); and therefore I get a Null Pointer exception, when I try to access a Item via listView.getChildAt(position).

Comment: Pity, that was just a guess hoping it'd work. What should definitely work is assigning an own adapter overriding `isEnabled`. Of course, that's less convenient ... p.s. will remove `getChildAt(position)` from my answer above

Comment: Sorry, but i'm kinda beginner. I can set an adapter for a listview. But how can i do it for a multichoice dialog?  When i do it like this: builder.setAdaper(myAdapter, ..., ClickHandler); it looses the option to select multiple values. After clicking an item in the list, the dialog closes.

Comment: Ok, I see. Have a look at my updated code. You get the list view from the `AlertDialog` and you can set your own adapter with `setAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out in the evening and let you know.

Comment: Sorry had no time to test it. I'll try it this weekend. Will definitely let you know.

Comment: Hi, your code works for me, but there are still some problems in my small app. The list items in dialog are white on white background. When i press them i can see the text because of the orange hover effect, but are "invisible" in their normal state. Enabling/disabling the items works to. Is it possible to hide/unhide rows likewise? Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: This looks like `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice` or `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` aren't the right choice. If all fails you could define an own layout. Check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html or instance http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/ for dialog customization. May be it works with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I came across this issue and I did not manage to find a solution on internet without using Custom Adapter. Finally I have a simple solution by using below code

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
      ListView lw = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
      if (which == 0) {
          //for example, disable second and third items after first item is selected
           final ListAdapter adaptor = lw.getAdapter();
           lw.getChildAt(1).setEnabled(false);
           lw.getChildAt(2).setEnabled(false);
      }
   }
```